# how to declare a variable as extern in objectivec,so that i can access that in any view controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, extern

i want to access the same variable in all view controllers ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extern is a C keyword, and works the same in Objective-C as in straight C.  In your header file, declare your variable:

```
extern NSString *myGlobal;
```

And then set it in your .m file.

*However*, this is frequently a poor coding practice; it is generally preferable to explicitly hand your view controllers some kind of state object or data source.

Comment: but i am not able to access this variable no longer in other views

Comment: are you #import'ing the header that declares the variable in each of your view files?

Comment: @lakiniphone I think you got a comment there, a few months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting in an extern for variables, store your data in the AppDelegate instance - or in some other singleton.  Then you can get to it, and modify it, from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

While I'll admit I still use the AppDelegate solution quite often, I believe the singleton design pattern is a better solution. [Here's a link to a solution and the reasoning.](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html)